# How do you successfully compile a C program using the GNU Readline library?

Tags: c, debugging, linker, gnu, readline

I followed the instructions to install GNU Readline, as well as Curses, however I get some linker issues that I am unsure how to resolve. The following is my program:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char * line = readline ("Enter a line: ");
    free (line);
    return 0;   
}
```

I compiled using: `gcc -o main {,.c} -lreadline -lncurses` (and the readline includes were where they were supposed to be, in usr/includes...

Running `main` gave me: 
`./main: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP`

Any direction as to go about resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you build the libraries yourself or did you install via a package manager?

Comment: I did it myself, followed to commands in the packages' READMEs.

Comment: configure and make for both `readline` and `curses` libraries

Comment: OOh one more: I'm working on the latest Ubuntu release...

Comment: When searching for the terms "libreadline UP", the second link was [this one](http://www.justskins.com/forums/readline-problem-libreadline-so-98137.html). Please read it and try again.

Comment: As an alternative, you could have installed the packages `libreadline6-dev` and `libncurses5-dev`. Your program, with the same command line for building, worked fine for me without hiccups, also on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: If you don't really need something special, just use the packages provided by your distribution. My hunch is that you used the system's `/usr/include` header files, and are now linking against a different library in `/usr/local/lib`. Does compiling with `gcc -I/usr/local/include ...` help by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
gcc -o main {,.c} -lreadline -lncurses
```